# Why does a narrower Gaussian wavepacket correspond to an increased $\Delta k$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fourier-transform

Please answer this question without too much reference to the Uncertainty Principle. I understand it in that respect. I'm just wondering in terms of Fourier analysis. Why does a more localized wave amount to a broader $k$-space spectrum needed to represent the wave? This doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Comment: What you are asking about IS the uncertainty principle. What answer do you expect not referencing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to see that this is the case is to work it out explicitly for the case of a Gaussian wave packet.  In this case, this property is a direct consequence of how the Gaussian function parameters appear in its Fourier transform. Explicitly, for a Gaussian function:

$$g(x)=e^{-ax^2}$$
$$\mathcal {F}[g(x)]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)e^{-2\pi i k x}dx=\sqrt {\frac {\pi}a}e^{\frac {-\pi^2 k^2}{a}}$$
How localized the Gaussian is, is measured by how fast it decays from its peak, and this is determined by the multiplicative constant in its exponent. So you can see that the paremeter $a$ determines how the Gaussian decays, so how localized it is. For the original spatial function, the bigger the $a$ the more localized it is, while for its Fourier transform the bigger the a, the less localized it is, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The two spaces have a sort of inverse relationship. Physical space is measured in m and k space is measured in 1/m.

This is the case for any two spaces related by the Fourier transform. By analogy, if you want a signal to be more localized in time (faster) then it needs to be broader in frequency. This is why broadband internet is faster.

So a Gaussian packet that has a width of 1 m in space will have a width of 1 1/m in k space. While a narrower packet in space, say 0.1 m, will have a width of 10 1/m in k space.

Answer (score 0):

$\let\D=\Delta \def\infinf{_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\!} 
\def\avg#1{\langle#1\rangle}$
Let $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)\ (\|f\|=1)$, $g$ its Fourier transform
$$g(k) = {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi}} 
  \int\limits\infinf f(x)\,e^{-ikx}\,dx$$
(note that also $\|g\|=1$). Define
$$f_a(x) = {1 \over \sqrt a}\,f(x/a) \quad (\|f_a\|=1).$$

Then the Fourier transform of $f_a$ is
$${1 \over \sqrt{2\pi a}} \int\limits\infinf f(x/a)\,e^{-ikx}\,dx =
  \sqrt{a \over 2\pi}\!\int\limits\infinf f(u)\,e^{-iaku}\,du = 
  \sqrt a\>g(ka) = g_a(k)$$
and $\|g_a\|=1$ too.

To simplify calculations let's assume $\avg x=0$, $\avg k=0$ (this puts no essential restriction on $f$). Then
$$\eqalign{(\D x)_{f_a}^{\,2} &= \avg{x^2}_{f_a} = 
  \int\limits\infinf x^2\,|f_a(x)|^2\,dx =
  {1 \over a}\!\int\limits\infinf x^2\,|f(x/a)|^2\,dx \cr 
  &= a^2\!\!\int\limits\infinf u^2\,|f(u)|^2\,du = 
     a^2\,(\D x)_f^{\,2}.\cr}$$
$$\eqalign{(\D k)_{g_a}^{\,2} &= \avg{k^2}_{g_a} = 
  \int\limits\infinf k^2\,|g_a(k)|^2\,dk =
  a\!\!\int\limits\infinf k^2\,|g(ka)|^2\,dk \cr 
  &= {1 \over a^2} \int\limits\infinf h^2\,|g(h)|^2\,dh = 
  {1 \over a^2}\,(\D k)_g^{\,2}.\cr}$$

Finally:
$$(\D x)_{f_a}\,(\D k)_{g_a} = (\D x_f)\,(\D k_g).$$
A general result (not for gaussian packets alone).